# Debugger popup message "Getting DataTip text"

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

This Debugger message pops up randomly while i am attempting to examine a variable while a breakpoint has hit in Visual Studio 2017.

Shortly thereafter, a larger message box appears that shows the following: "Evaluating the function 'System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadForm' timed out."

After enabling option **Tools / Options / Debugging / General / Only managed code**, the second message box have disappeared. But first message is still showing.

The problem is that first popup window appears for a relatively long time, that makes debugging process very noncomfortable. What else Visual Studio debugger options could I set to disable this popup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1)Tools->Options, uncheck the setting Debugging / General / Enable property evaluation and other implicit function call, and enable the Use Managed Compatibility Mode.

(2)Deleted all the .suo/obj/Bin/.user files in your project, and then re-open your project, clean and build your solution, debug it again.

Comment: This solution does not suit me, since it does not allow me to use the full power of the debugger, I can not see the values ​​of the properties.

Comment: @Aave, It was just a workaround I could get, it really has some limitations if disable that option. If possible, I suggest you submit a feedback to the report team, you could also share a simple sample there, so the product team could repro this issue and provide useful information: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html

Comment: The Clean Build seemed to work.  Gotta love those new "features" in VS!  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This solution works fine for me:

Uncheck the new langage JavasScript Language Service in Options -> Editor -> JavaScript -> Language Service.

[Option capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA567.png)

Comment: Sorry, this solution was not helped me(

Answer (score 2):

I'm having this same issue and there doesn't appear to be a solution.  It's extremely frustrating because when the "Getting DataTip text..." does popup and eventually goes away, my breakpoints no longer work.

The solutions listed here have not solved the problem, I've tried them ALL ... even a wipe and re-install of OS and VS 2015.

Debugging without ability to do property evaluation and other implicit function calls is basically NOT debugging and defeats the purpose.

Microsoft seem to be aware of the problem but keep closing the tickets as "unable to replicate" ... yet, a simple Google Search will show many many thousands of hits of developers running into this problem.  I keep opening tickets with Microsoft, but they just keep getting closed or merged with no solution.

Cheers, Rob.

Comment: I still have this problem, although more than year gone and VS was updated few times. So, do MS not hurry fix this bug?

Answer (score 2):

The ONLY solution that worked for me:

1. CMD window (Run As Admin)
2. type SFC /SCANNOW and wait for it to complete and hopefully fix any errors
3. Reboot
4. Bring up VS 2015 or 2017 without loading any project
5. In VS select Tools | Import and Export Settings | Reset all Setting ... now pick the template you use (i.e. VB, C, Web)
6. Exit VS
7. Load VS project and debug

Cheers, Rob.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it. The problem is still actual.

Comment: Unfortunately the fix I listed above appears to be temporary.  I have since started experiencing the problem again after 2 weeks of not having the issue.

Comment: I checked this, and in my case SFC don't found any problems. So this solution is not suitable for me, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Old post, but maybe it will help someone anyway ;)

In my case I got this every time I examined the first variable while debugging.
Annoying as hell as I due to the nature of the work restart the debugger often.

This was cause by that the location where my Visual Studio 2017 files were saved, was a cloud drive and it actually had to sync the files before showing the data.

The solution was to mark that whole folder "Always keep on this device".

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

​Here is one possible solution:

I had this error never seen - then my graphics card (Nvidia) was gone and I removed the graphics card and worked with the integrated Intel. Then I got this error in after 3-4 steps. I installed a Nvidia again and now the "getting data" text message was never shown again.

Btw: this was the fix for the error

"64 bit debugging operation is taking longer than expected"

Comment: Hm. I use integrated Intel video card, too.

Comment: Hmm... I'm a laptop with integrated video. As the company owns the device and laptops are notorious for being compact with no room for upgrades or changes, I think I'm stuck. :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I wanted to evaluate variables while debugging in my Unit tests and couldn't find any solution.

This is the solution that helped me: Tools -> Options / Debugging / General. Uncheck "Call string-conversion function on objects in variables windows".

This might only work for some people.

Comment: Unfortunately, not helped in my case...((

Comment: I installed VS with offline installer DVD, and my PC haven't internet connection, so I can not update software. My second PC, connected to the internet, and VS, that was installed from the same DVD, after downloading updates, now works normally. Probably, missed some dependences?..

Comment: I have no idea. I found this solution pretty weird as my colleagues use the same visual studio version and they have that option checked. That's why I said "This might only work for some people" as this option is checked by default I think.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue. I also got this every time I examined the first variable while debugging.

In my case, it happened when I hit a breakpoint inside a C# nested function.

```
static void doSomething(Input input)
{
    static void doSomethingImpl(Input input)
    {
        // breakpoint here
    }
    doSomethingImpl(input);
}
```

Moving `doSomethingImpl` outside of `doSomething` fixed the issue.

Note: it is a Unity Mono build.